# Select a Cell in a TableView and changed size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, io

I need to set my `UITableView` cells, when I select a cell increases its size to twice, and if I select another this increase in size and decrease that was previously selected size.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.states count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.stateName.text = [self.states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take

one property selectedIndexPath

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath * selectedIndexPath;
```

set that in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
[tableView reloadData];
}


-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath == selectedIndexPath){
        return 80;
}

    return 40;
}
```

Comment: how declare selectedindexpath identifier ?

Comment: create a property in h file like

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath * selectedIndexPath;

Comment: thanks!!! it works!!!!

this is how the method stay
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];
}


-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(_selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath == _selectedIndexPath){
        return 80;
    }
    
    return 40;
}

Comment: how to hide the label if this cell is not selected

Comment: than you have to get to check in cellforrowatindex if selectedindexpath then label is not hidden unless it is hidden, you have to reload every time in didselect

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout then simply add

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // for particular index 
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

and if not using autolayout then

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 1){
           return 80;
        }else{
          return 44;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't use autolayout, i think i need use didselect or something